# Vertical aspect ratio media query

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I want to achieve the opposite of this media query:

```
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .name {
        background: blue;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Therefore aspect ratio `9/16` for a vertical one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the aspect ratio in the media query to `9/16`.

```
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 9/16) {
    .name {
        background: blue;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! tested it before and it didn't work. tested it now and it worked! Thanks.